# Compare groups of 4 characters to see if they're the same in a string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to use Python to compare two strings and see if any of them have common groups of `4` letters.

```
sequence1 = "ACACGCGTCTCCTTGCGGGTAAAT"
sequence2 = "GTTACCAATTTCTTGTTTCCGAAT"

for i in range(0,24,4):
    print i
    list1.append(sequence1[i:i+4])

for i in range(0,24,4):
    print i
    list2.append(sequence2[i:i+4])
```

But this doesn't seem to do it. I want it to return the groups of letters that are equal in both strings, any ideas?

Comment: oops forgot to put the code

Comment: still unclear what you want

Comment: Does it matter common ones' indexes? Does it considered of having common ones if one has ATTG at first four places and the other one has somewhere in middle?

Comment: It does need to be the same 4 places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over groups of `4` by using a list comprehension together with slicing. I have edited the sequences to contain two common 4 letter elements:

```
s1 = "ACACGCGGTCTCTTGCGGGAAATT"
s2 = "GTTACCAATTTCTTGCTTCCAAAT"

c = [s1[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s1), 4) if s1[i:i+4] in s2]
```

The list `c` now contains the common entries: `['TTGC', 'AAAT']`

Do note, this does not discriminate on position; if that is required you simply change the `if` statement in the list comprehension to define that:

```
c = [s1[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(s1), 4) if s1[i:i+4] == s2[i:i+4]]
```

Now it contains only `['TTGC']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sequence1 = "ACACGCGTCTCCTTGCGGGTAAAT"
sequence2 = "GTTACCAATTTCTTGTTTCCGAAT"

for i in range(len(sequence1) - 4):
    if sequence1[i:i+4] == sequence2[i:i+4]:
        print sequence1[i:i+4]
```

This will compare the same index of the 4 letters